# Concatenating two regex strings in rust

Tags: regex, rust

I have two variables that hold the string version of a regex expression. I want to create a third variable that represents the OR of those variables and am having a difficult time writing this in rust.

```rust
const numbers: &str = "/[0-9]/";
const letters: &str = "/[a-z]/";

const numbers_and_letters: &str = "([0-9]|[a-z])";
```

The numbers_and_letters variable is the one I want to construct but I want to do it using references to the numbers and letters variable.

```rust
const numbers_and_letters: &str = format!("{}|{}", numbers, letters);
```

A few things to note:

1. the numbers_and_letters must be of type `&str`
2. we may need to slice the beginning & end char of the strings (i.e. `/`, `/`).

I've been running into issues with the compiler. Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: I might be missing something but why do you have `/` characters in the regex?

Answer (score 3):

## First of all

Ad-hoc combination of bits of regex seems like a terrible, terrible idea and a high likelyhood of [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Are you sure you're not looking for e.g. [`RegexSet`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.4.3/regex/struct.RegexSet.html), or a proper parser combinator like [`nom`](https://github.com/Geal/nom), or something along those lines?

## Help yourself by helping would-be helpers

> I've been running into issues with the compiler.

The compiler generates error messages. Those error messages provide valuable information. When the compiler tells you something and you want help with that, *paste what the compiler is telling you*.

Providing a complete reproduction case on https://play.rust-lang.org is also appreciated.

> ```
> const numbers_and_letters: &str = format!("{}|{}", numbers, letters);
> ```

That rather obviously makes no sense on its face: `format!` needs to allocate a new string, and thus returns a `String`. So it's out.

A second issue is that `const` probably doesn't do what you think it does, and your globals should most likely be `static` variables not `const`.

## Possible solution of the *stated* question, which may be the wrong one entirely

- the classic way to create non-constexpr statics is [`lazy_static`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) or [`once_cell`](https://crates.io/crates/once_cell), you can format the `String` with lazy_static then borrow *that* to an `&str`:

  ```rust
  use lazy_static::lazy_static; // 1.4.0

  static A: &'static str = "a";
  static B: &'static str = "b";
  lazy_static! {
      static ref C: String = format!("{}|{}", A, B);
      // not actually useful, you could borrow `C` at use-site
      static ref D: &'static str = &C;
  }
  ```

  The advantages are that it's a well known pattern (and crate) and it works in a wide variety of rustc. It also lets you perform any runtime transformation you may want to so stripping bits of the string is not an issue.

  The drawbacks are that you're handrolling it and that your type is being wrapped in a special structure so you'll have to dereference `D` (or `C` for that matter) to actually access its contents, otherwise you're just getting the wrapper type constructed by `lazy_static`.
- alternatively using a relatively recent compiler you can use [const_format](https://crates.io/crates/const_format) which as its name indicate is a constexpr-version of `format!`.

  The advantage is it's simpler and more straightforward than lazy_static or once_cell.

  The drawbacks are that it's a much less popular pattern and crate, it requires a recent compiler, and [constant expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html) may not yet support all the operations you need.